# Is using Push-Location/Pop-Location beneficial when editing the registry?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, registry

Here's my own script with Push/Pop lines in question. Got the PushPop idea from [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1951220-script-to-add-reg-key-powershell-help). They're # commented because they apparently don't do anything...functionally afaik.

```
# DisableCortana.ps1
 
$newKeyLocation="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"
$newKeyName="Windows Search"
 
#Push-Location       # "Adds that location at the top of the stack" - for what?
# I guess if your location is changed mid-thread execution, this could make sense, but how could that be allowed in the first place?
Set-Location $newKeyLocation
 
if(Test-Path "$newKeyLocation\$newKeyname"){
    echo "Path exists, aborting"
 
}else{
 
New-Item -Path "$newKeyLocation" -Name "$newKeyName"
 
$newKey="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search"
$newValueName="AllowCortana"
$allowCortanaValue="0"
 
New-ItemProperty -Path $newKey -Name $newValueName -Value $allowCortanaValue `
-PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
 
#Pop-Location
}
```

Comment: What do you mean they don't do anything?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` are here to guarantee the current location  is not modified by your script.

In a new new PowerShell session Test :

```
Get-Location 
$newKeyLocation="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"
$a = Set-Location $newKeyLocation 
Get-Location
```

Look the prop has changed, you are no longer in the default file system provider but in the registry  provider.

And now take a new PowerShell session and Test :

```
Get-Location 
Push-Location
$newKeyLocation="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"
$a = Set-Location $newKeyLocation 
Pop-Location
Get-Location
```

The prompt stay in the file system

I think that you may have a look to [About Providers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7). The location is working on the top of providers so `set-location`, `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` are globaly working on different PSDrives which are not only file system but, can be registry, Alias (see get-psprovider, get-psdrive)

Comment: I'll get this tested out once Im back at workstation and get back to here to mark correct, thank you!